# OleDbProvider, db2, E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: c#, db2

In some servers get following Error:

```
'IBMDADB2' failed with no error message available, 
      result code:    E_FAIL(0x80004005).     
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr) 
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.BuildSchemaTableRowset(Object handle) 
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GenerateSchemaTable(
     OleDbDataReader dataReader, Object handle, CommandBehavior behavior) 
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
     behavior, String method) 
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(
     CommandBehavior behavior) 
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchemaInternal(DataSet dataset, 
     DataTable datatable, SchemaType schemaType, IDbCommand command,
     String srcTable, CommandBehavior behavior) at 
     System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet dataSet,
     SchemaType schemaType, IDbCommand command, String srcTable, CommandBehavior behavior) 
     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet dataSet,
     SchemaType schemaType) 
     at BusinessLogiс.DB2.Database.GetData(String query, 
     String database, String host, String port, String login, String password)
```

**GetData Method:**

```
public static DataTable GetData(string query, string database,
             string host, string port, string login, string password)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = Connection.GetConnection(database, host, port, login, password);
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

            return dataSet.Tables[0];
        }
        finally 
        {
            Connection.CloseConnection(connection);
        }
    }
```

**connectionString:**

```
connectionString = string.Format("Provider=IBMDADB2;
                    Database={0};Hostname={1};
                    Protocol=TCPIP;Port={2};
                    Uid ={3};Pwd={4};", 
                    database, host, port, login, password);
```

Comment: Did you **open** your connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted a line

```
dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to open connexion.

FillSchema is not really necessary if you want only query and update your database.

You can use idb2connexion, idb2dataadapter in ADO.NET, its better

[Example here](http://timtrott.co.uk/querying-iseries-db2-adonet/)